# Joomla 3 and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I have overridden component com_content and category view inside, so it looks like:

```
/templates/my_template/html/com_content/category
```

needed file is **blog.php**. Here outputs my php calendar.

```
<?php

  JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addScript('/space/media/media/js/mainscript.js');

  function days_in_month($month, $year) 
  { 
    // calculate number of days in a month 
    return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31); 
  }

  $currentYear = date('Y');
  $currentMonth = date('n');

  $rusmonth = array('Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь');

  $dayofmonth = days_in_month($currentMonth, $currentYear);;

  $day_count = 1;

  $num = 0;
  for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
  {

    $dayofweek = date('w',
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), $day_count, date('Y')));

    $dayofweek = $dayofweek - 1;
    if($dayofweek == -1) $dayofweek = 6;

    if($dayofweek == $i)
    {

      $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
      $day_count++;
    }
    else
    {
      $week[$num][$i] = "";
    }
  }

  while(true)
  {
    $num++;
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
      $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
      $day_count++;
      if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
    }
    if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
  }

  echo '<div> <span id="prev" data-month="'.$currentMonth.'" data-year="'.$currentYear.'"><</span> '.$rusmonth[$currentMonth-1].' <span id="next" data-month="'.$currentMonth.'" data-year="'.$currentYear.'">></span>  </div>';
  echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
    echo '<table border=1>';
    echo '<tr>
            <th>ПН</th>
            <th>ВТ</th>
            <th>СР</th>
            <th>ЧТ</th>
            <th>ПТ</th>
            <th>СБ</th>
            <th>ВС</th>
           </tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($week); $i++)
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
      {
        if(!empty($week[$i][$j]))
        {

          if($j == 5 || $j == 6) 
               echo "<td><font color=red>".$week[$i][$j]."</font></td>";
          else echo "<td>".$week[$i][$j]."</td>";
        }
        else echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";


} 
    echo "</table>";
  echo '</div>';
?>
```

at the top of file i add my script which switching months.
Here is the code of `mainscript.js`:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict()
j(document).ready(function(){

    j('#next').click(function(){

        var month = j(this).data('month');
        var year = j(this).data('year');

        if(month == 12){
            year +=1;
            month = 1;
        }
        else{
            month++;
        }

        j.ajax({
         url: "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&task=getAjaxData&format=raw",
         type: "POST",
         async: true,
         data: {
                month: month,
                year: year

         },
         success: function(data){ 
           j('#calendar_wrap').html(data);
           j(this).data('month', month);
             j(this).data('year', year);

             console.log('month: '+j(this).data('month')+' year: '+j(this).data('year'));
          }
        });

    })

    j('#prev').click(function(){

        var month = j(this).data('month');
        var year = j(this).data('year');

        if(month == 1){
            year -=1;
            month = 12;

        }
        else{
            month--;
        }

        j.ajax({
         url: "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&task=getAjaxData&format=raw",
         type: "POST",
         async: true,
         data: {
                month: month,
                year: year

         },
         success: function(data){ 
            j('#calendar_wrap').html(data);
            j(this).data('month', month);
              j(this).data('year', year);
              console.log('month: '+j(this).data('month')+' year: '+j(this).data('year'));
          }
        });

    })
});
```

And to make my script work i have added to /com_content/controller.php

method

```
    public function getAjaxData()
      {

            JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

            $document = JFactory::getDocument();
            $document->addScript('/space/media/media/js/mainscript.js');

          function days_in_month($month, $year) 
          { 
            // calculate number of days in a month 
            return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31); 
          }

          // Вычисляем число дней в текущем месяце

          $currentYear = date('Y');
          $currentMonth = date('n');
          if(isset($_REQUEST['year']))
            $currentYear = $_REQUEST['year'];
          if(isset($_REQUEST['month']))
            $currentMonth = $_REQUEST['month'];


          $rusmonth = array('Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь');

          $dayofmonth = days_in_month($currentMonth, $currentYear);
          // Счётчик для дней месяца
          $day_count = 1;

          // 1. Первая неделя
          $num = 0;
          for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
          {
            // Вычисляем номер дня недели для числа
            $dayofweek = date('w',
                              mktime(0, 0, 0, $currentMonth, $day_count, $currentYear));
            // Приводим к числа к формату 1 - понедельник, ..., 6 - суббота
            $dayofweek = $dayofweek - 1;
            if($dayofweek == -1) $dayofweek = 6;

            if($dayofweek == $i)
            {
              // Если дни недели совпадают,
              // заполняем массив $week
              // числами месяца
              $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
              $day_count++;
            }
            else
            {
              $week[$num][$i] = "";
            }
          }

          // 2. Последующие недели месяца
          while(true)
          {
            $num++;
            for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
            {
              $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
              $day_count++;
              // Если достигли конца месяца - выходим
              // из цикла
              if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
            }
            // Если достигли конца месяца - выходим
            // из цикла
            if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
          }

          // 3. Выводим содержимое массива $week
          // в виде календаря
          // Выводим таблицу
          echo '<div> <span id="prev" data-month="'.$currentMonth.'" data-year="'.$currentYear.'"><</span> '.$rusmonth[$currentMonth-1].' <span id="next" data-month="'.$currentMonth.'" data-year="'.$currentYear.'">></span>  </div>';
          echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
            echo '<table border=1>';
            echo '<tr>
                        <th>ПН</th>
                        <th>ВТ</th>
                        <th>СР</th>
                        <th>ЧТ</th>
                        <th>ПТ</th>
                        <th>СБ</th>
                        <th>ВС</th>
                     </tr>';
            for($i = 0; $i < count($week); $i++)
            {
              echo "<tr>";
              for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
              {
                if(!empty($week[$i][$j]))
                {
                  // Если имеем дело с субботой и воскресенья
                  // подсвечиваем их
                  if($j == 5 || $j == 6) 
                       echo "<td><font color=red>".$week[$i][$j]."</font></td>";
                  else echo "<td>".$week[$i][$j]."</td>";
                }
                else echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
              }
              echo "</tr>";
            } 
            echo "</table>";
          echo '</div>';


exit;
  }
```

It is doing exactly the same, as blog.php, but with new values that were transfered by ajax.
So there are two ways i see to solve the problem.

1. Find a way to use my method in controller like a bridge between script and blog.php, so i have only one place to output calendar.
2. add my script to controller, so i could use my script not only from blog.php, but i don't like that way..

So i'll be happy to get any ideas from you

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is exactly?

Comment: after i switching the month, my ajax addresses to controller file. From this moment my script doesn't included to the program, because it have been added in overridden blog.php